# Volume appears extremely dim in render compared to rendered view in the viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, fire

So, I ran a fire simulation, then imported the result as a .vdb file. I applied this shader:

[image: node setup for fire shader]

and that produces this result *when viewed in the rendered-mode viewport*

[image]

When I hit F12 and render the frame, though, this is what I get:

[image]

I'm really unsure what's going on here. If anyone has had or knows of a similar problem and could point me towards a solution, I'd be greatly indebted. I would really like the final output to look even remotely close to what I see in the rendered-mode viewport.

I'm running Blender 2.90.1 on a 2013 MacBook Pro. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Disabling Film: Transparent fixes the issue, but leaves me with the problem of... not have the transparent background I need. I'm going to fiddle with Alpha Blending Modes (which apparently is still an option you can mess with in Cycles)

EDIT 2: Alpha Blend Modes have no effect on the issue. Current fix is just not putting alpha transparency behind the volume. Would love a better solution still.

EDIT 3: Attempted to use Holdout to solve, had no real success. Right now, I've resorted to rendering on a pure black background and just going the traditional route of using the add blend mode in compositing.

Comment: Are you rendering in cycles or eevee?

Comment: @J.Chan Cycles, although the issue persists in Eevee as well. Seems to be related to there being transparency behind the volume.